# Python Float Formatting Minimum Characters

Tags: python, string, numbers, format

I am reading a large ascii file, converting to binary, and compressing it to reduce file size.  I would like to reproduce the original file exactly.  However, number formatting is an issue.  I believe the original file is printed with the minimum number of characters required to uniquely identify the floating point number.

```
import struct
x = [3.14, 3.1]
y = list(struct.unpack('2f', struct.pack('2f', *x)))
print str(x)
print str(y)
```

Which returns
    [3.14, 3.1]
    [3.140000104904175, 3.0999999046325684]

I would like to print y exactly like x.  How can I do that?  Also, I don't understand what magic is taking place under the hood with the str function.  Can you please explain?  I am using Python 2.7.

Update:

```
import struct
x = [3.14, 3.1]
y = list(struct.unpack('2d', struct.pack('2d', *x)))
print str(x)
print str(y)
```

The code above returns:

```
[3.14, 3.1]
[3.14, 3.1]
```

So the str function truncates characters, but only when the value is very close to to the 64 bit floating point value.  I would like similiar behavior when the value is very close to the 32 bit floating point value.

Comment: Yours is a [duplicate question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689004/format-a-float-to-a-string-with-minimum-characters-in-python), I'd suggest that you remove your old question or, better, remove this one and edit the previous one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is that a python float is 64 bit.  Casting to numpy.float32 before calling str() results in a number formatted as I want.

```
print str(np.float32(y[0]))
```

prints

```
3.14
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for i in y:
    print "%.2f" % i
```

all `str()` does is just convert the object it is given to a string